# Under which circumstances does GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() block in .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading, garbage-collection, finalizer

Quoting from the MSDN documentation for [GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers.aspx):

> The thread on which finalizers are run is unspecified, so there is no guarantee that this method will terminate.

I don't really understand this sentence. Under which circumstances does this method not terminate? And what does this have to do with the thread the finalizer runs on? Why do they state that the thread is "unspecified"?

Regarding the finalizer thread, I assume the following is correct(?):

- There's only *one* finalizer thread.
- The finalizers always run on a separate thread (i.e. never on the main thread, or any other user created thread).

*Note:* I can imagine this method will block when one of the finalizers blocks, but this problem exist no matter what thread is being used for the finalizers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [another article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx):

> The Finalize method might not run to completion or might not run at
>   all in the following exceptional circumstances:
>
> - Another finalizer blocks indefinitely (goes into an infinite loop,
>     tries to obtain a lock it can never obtain and so on). Because the
>     runtime attempts to run finalizers to completion, other finalizers
>     might not be called if a finalizer blocks indefinitely.
> - The process terminates without giving the runtime a chance to clean
>     up. In this case, the runtime's first notification of process
>     termination is a DLL_PROCESS_DETACH notification.

Comment: Ok, but then why does the documentation explicitly state that the "thread on which finalizers are run is unspecified"? Wouldn't it be enough to just write "There is no guarantee that this method will terminate (because of blocking finalizers)"?

Comment: I think it's to say that the CLR team want the right to change implementation details in the future, and they don't want you to count on how it works today. The fact is that they run on their own thread (not the one called GC.Collect).

Comment: In Richter's CLR via C#, I believe he mentions (much like Shahar wrote) that in the future, the CLR may use multiple finalizer threads. I don't have the book handy, but I would think an in-depth discussion could be found in it that might better answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you usually don't need to use methods in GC class, except probably for SuppressFinalize. Most of the other methods will usually makes you application performs worst, not better.

But, to answer your questions, as far as i know when collection performed there is internal list held by the garbage collector of finalizers to run, **and they all run sequencally on the same thread**. Which means, that if one finalizer block then i guess this method will block too.

When app domain shuts down, there is a time limit for all finalizers to finish, and in that case i guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Please see comment on Richard Morgan's answer.